Money exchange error in favor
If you agreed to the clerk at the exchange to sell 5 zuz for 10 dollars. You give 5 zuz. They count the money, give you receipt and both 5 zuz and 10 dollars through a small window on a plate
What's the status of 10 dollars if you keep them?
No deceit was applied. Is that a lost article?
Is transaction null and you just picked up someone's money off the plate?
Basically they agreed to buy currency for a particular price but in the end they return the currency and hand the payment for the currency.

This is basically the same thing as getting extra change at a grocery store.
This would be considered Hashavat Aveida, as it is included in that mitzvah to stop others from incurring losses. However, Hashavat Aveida only applies between fellow jews (Sefer Hachinuch 538). I will assume that the currency exchange people are non-jewish, in which case although it is not obligatory, it is certainly commendable as it would cause a Kiddush Hashem.
If, the currency exchange people are Jewish, one is expected to go to great lengths to do Hashavat Aveida.
